# Register specifier appearing in the function argument

Tags: c++, register-keyword

I'm trying to understand, what is the point of applying `register` specifier to a function argument. The following code is valid:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct A
{
    A(){ cout << "A\n"; } 
    ~A(){ cout << "~A\n"; }
};

void foo(register A a)
{
}

int main()
{
    cout << "first line\n";
    foo(A());
    cout << "last line\n";
}
```

Why does `register` specifier apply to function parameter?

Comment: What's the point of applying it anywhere anymore?

Comment: There's no point. `register` is a no-op, whether applied to parameters or otherwise. It exists for backward compatibility only. Having said that: a function parameter is, for most intents and purposes, a local variable. To the extent `register` is meaningful for local variables, it's equally meaningful for parameters.

Comment: Well probably [dcl.stc]/3 also applies to function parameters: "A `register` specifier is a hint to the implementation that the variable so declared will be heavily used."

Comment: Note that "The use of the `register` keyword as a *storage-class-specifier* is deprecated." [depr.register]

Answer (score 2):

`register` is an old keyword that has its origins way back in K&R C. It's purpose was to hint the compiler to keep the variable as a processor register, instead of loading and unloading the data from memory, which had overhead. When you access this variable very often the one or two instructions you saved when you declare it as register was very valuable back then.

Since then compilers have became pretty good at optimizing your code, and this keyword lost its purpose. It's now ignored by most implementations unless you tell the compiler to use it anyway.